# How to attach role before request check for the role in Spring Security, SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openid-connect

I am using OIDC JWT token to costume spring rest API, but to access a few URL requests must have certain roles like

```java
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/reports/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "WRITE_1", "WRITE_2")
```

But Rest Api returning 403, I figure out that, the request has missed the role, Is there any way
I can extract the user name and find the role respect this user name and attach back to the request. So that when Role check perform request should have the required role?

Comment: Which roles does your user have? the `hasAnyRole`, in this case, would expect them to be `ROLE_ADMIN`,. `ROLE_WRITE_1` or `ROLE_WRITE_2`... If that is not what you want either set the default prefix to empty, or use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Comment: Any role can access mention routes.

Comment: You can check in debug : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().

Roles / authorities are added during authentication phase.